# How to build an objectmapper to handle json objects

Tags: java, json, object

I'm new to the whole concept of REST and mapping json into a Java Object.  I know that I need to create a class file that the object mapper uses to create the Java object. The json below is what is top end returned from WeatherUnderground using a resttemplate.  To me, it appears to be an array of objects and I am only interested at the moment in the current_observation and the display_location objects.  It also appears to have several objects imbedded in other objects.

The arrays I think I can figure out, but can anyone give me some pointers on how to map a json object.

Thanks,
Rob

```
{
"response": {
"version": "0.1",
"termsofService": "http://www.wunderground.com/weather/api/d/terms.html",
"features": {
"conditions": 1
}
},
"current_observation": {
"image": {
"url": "http://icons-ak.wxug.com/graphics/wu2/logo_130x80.png",
"title": "Weather Underground",
"link": "http://www.wunderground.com"
},
"display_location": {
"full": "San Francisco, CA",
"city": "San Francisco",
"state": "CA",
"state_name": "California",
"country": "US",
"country_iso3166": "US",
"zip": "94101",
"latitude": "37.77500916",
"longitude": "-122.41825867",
"elevation": "47.00000000"
},
```

Comment: If you are interested in what exactly JSON is, you can look [here](http://www.json.org/). REST and JSON are 2 entirely different things, so make sure are not intermixing them. The first thing to note is that what you provided is **not** valid JSON (you can check that [here](http://jsonlint.com/)). It isn't entirely clear what your goal is. Is it to get from JSON to a Java object you define? Do you just want to parse this JSON using a library?

Answer (score 0):

You'll find it is actually pretty easy, I'd recommend [Jackson 2](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind), it has a lot of good documentation and is widely used.

As a basic usage for you sample, I created a Java POJO to map your response sample to it.

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;

import java.util.Map;    

@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class Response {

    private Map<String, Object> response;


    @JsonProperty("current_observation")
    private Map<String, Object> currentObservation;


    public Map<String, Object> getResponse() {
        return response;
    }

    public void setResponse(Map<String, Object> response) {
        this.response = response;
    }

    public Map<String, Object> getCurrentObservation() {
        return currentObservation;
    }

    public void setCurrentObservation(Map<String, Object> currentObservation) {
        this.currentObservation = currentObservation;
    }
}
```

Then a Test class to test your response and bind it to the POJO.

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

import java.io.IOException;

public class Test {


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();


        String responseString = "{\n" +
                                "\"response\": {\n" +
                                "\"version\": \"0.1\",\n" +
                                "\"termsofService\": \"http://www.wunderground.com/weather/api/d/terms.html\",\n" +
                                "\"features\": {\n" +
                                "\"conditions\": 1\n" +
                                "}\n" +
                                "},\n" +
                                "\"current_observation\": {\n" +
                                "\"image\": {\n" +
                                "\"url\": \"http://icons-ak.wxug.com/graphics/wu2/logo_130x80.png\",\n" +
                                "\"title\": \"Weather Underground\",\n" +
                                "\"link\": \"http://www.wunderground.com\"\n" +
                                "},\n" +
                                "\"display_location\": {\n" +
                                "\"full\": \"San Francisco, CA\",\n" +
                                "\"city\": \"San Francisco\",\n" +
                                "\"state\": \"CA\",\n" +
                                "\"state_name\": \"California\",\n" +
                                "\"country\": \"US\",\n" +
                                "\"country_iso3166\": \"US\",\n" +
                                "\"zip\": \"94101\",\n" +
                                "\"latitude\": \"37.77500916\",\n" +
                                "\"longitude\": \"-122.41825867\",\n" +
                                "\"elevation\": \"47.00000000\"\n" +
                                "}\n" +
                                "}\n" +
                                "}";

        try {
            Response response = objectMapper.readValue(responseString, Response.class);


            System.out.print("Output: "+ response.getResponse().get("termsofService"));


        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

The output of the main method that prints the termsOfService from the sample response:

`Output: http://www.wunderground.com/weather/api/d/terms.html`

Hope it helps,

José Luis

Answer (score 0):

I think that you want to make `Json` decode into `Object`. Many `Json` libraries support such feature.

Take [FastJson](https://github.com/alibaba/fastjson) as example:

Suppose that you have class **HelloObject**:

```
// in HelloObject.java
public class HelloObject
{
    private DisplayLocation display_location;

    // and other members

    // setter and getter
    // ....
}

// in DisplayLocation.java
public class DisplayLocation{

    private String full;
    private String city;

    // and other members

    // setter and getter
    // ...
}

// main
String jsonString = ...;
HelloObject object = JSON.parseObject(jsonString, HelloObject.class);
```

By the way, [FastJson](https://github.com/alibaba/fastjson) is the fastest `JSON` library in `Java`, much better than `gson`.

Answer (score 0):

JSON has built-in data types - string, boolean, object, etc - so you just need to follow these based on the canonical data model of your JSON.  For example, you have the following classes above:

- Response
- Observation
- Image
- Location
- Conditions

plus a wrapper object around the whole thing that we can call ResponseWrapper.

In Java, you need to create the individual classes, so Image would be something like

```
public class Image {
    private String url;
    private String title;
    private String link;

    // getter and setters
}
```

The name of the property should match that of the JSON.  However, if you want to use something different you can specify that with annotations.  For example, you might wish to have `displayLocation` instead of `display_location` so if you're using Jackson it would be

```
@JsonProperty("display_location")
private String displayLocation;
```

At a higher level, you then aggregate these - ResponseWrapper, for example, would contain the following

```
public class ResponseWrapper {
    private Response response;
    @JsonProperty("current_observation")
    private CurrentObservation currentObservation;
    // ...and so on
}
```